# Web page open by Intent.ACTION_VIEW looks zoomed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

I built a very simple web page for online FAQ reference.
This is basically a plain html page with very few css.

When I open it form my PC brawser it looks just fine, also when I open it from different smartphones (in default brawser) it looks cool in all of them.

Now my problems rises when I try to open it inside my mobile app by calling an intent with ACTION_VIEW like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://my.domain.it:8443/FAQ/")));
```

In fact this leads to different behaviours depending on the device used to perform this action. Samsung S2 displays it right, but most of the other devices (i.e. Samsung Note, all Galaxys...) display the site much more zoomed than in ordinary brawser's view, also the zoom seems to be somehow 'fixed' as even zooming out the view won't turn it to the regular brawser correct view.

Is there something I can do for this? I've been googling this for a while but couldn't find a single helpful link.

**EDIT**

I validated the HTML and the CSS with an online validator and it gives "Valid" in both.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your site for HTML or CSS errors. Your issue got nothing in common with android really, but the way 3rd party application interpret your HTML/CSS

Comment: so why the issue shows only through Intent.ACTION_VIEW when all actual smartphone brawsers display it correctly?

Comment: I validated it right now with an HTML and CSS validator, but still gives the same issue...